# Apache Nutch 2.1 - Skipping http://someurl.com/something.html; different batch id (null)

Tags: java, apache, nutch

I crawl few sites with Apache Nutch 2.1.

While crawling I see the following message on lot of pages:
ex. Skipping http://videos.arte.tv/fr/videos/x-enius--7453284.html; different batch id (null)

What causes this error? It is while parsing phase...
How can I resolve this problem, I use HBase to store the pages.

My urls in regex-urlfilter.txt looks like

- +^http://([a-z0-9]*.)*videos.arte.tv/
- +^http://([a-z0-9]*.)*rbb-online.de/

but I also tried with same effect

- +^http://videos.arte.tv/
- +^http://www.rbb-online.de/

**EDIT:** It was added to track by maintainer of mailing list like bug, you can read here http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Nutch-2-1-different-batch-id-null-td4040592.html#a4059636

Answer (score 0):

I think, the message is not problem. batch_id not assigned to all of url. So, if batch_id is null , skip url. Generate url when batch_id assined for url.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828438/apache-nutch-2-1-different-batch-id-null/16079418#16079418).

Comment: There is a problem that I want to crawl a lot of websites... When a lot of pages are skipped, I have very few collected metadates and it is bad for me. And I also dont know why the page http://videos.arte.tv/de/videos/arte-reportage--7471210.html is fetched and parsed and for example the page http://videos.arte.tv/de/videos/real-humans-echte-menschen-7-10-achtung-schockierende-bilder--7455402.html is skipped... and most of the other pages of the domain arte.tv is skipped... it is the same domain name so why?

Comment: No problem. Because, "skipped urls" crawl at the next crawler.

Comment: You think that,if you have too many same domain, urls is crawled continuously for the domain and may be the another domains are crawled after a long time.

Comment: It was added to track by maintainer of mailing-list. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Nutch-2-1-different-batch-id-null-td4040592.html#a4059636